# Xamarin и USB устройство

Tags: android, c#, xamarin, usb

Возникла необходимость подключение сканера штрихкодов к телефону на Android. Подключение сканера будет через USB порт. В уже разработанном приложении есть сканер штрихкодов с использованием камеры телефона, но так же нужно добавить поддержку сканера как устройство USB. И тут возникла проблема как это реализовать. Читал информацию на https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/, на SO тоже ничего подобного не нашел (может плохо искал..), https://metanit.com/sharp/xamarin/ здесь тоже ни слова об устройствах подключаемых к телефону.

Может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой? 
Что нужно вообще использовать для работы с USB? как проверить подключено ли устройство, отправить какую-то команду и получить ответ?

**PS** Самого сканера USB еще нет, но нужно понять как с ним работать и возможно ли это вообще. Данные сканеры довольно дорогие, чтобы покупать их не глядя.

Интересующий сканер: [здесь](https://www.oldi.ru/catalog/element/0463743/)

Comment: Физическое устройство сканер ШК подключается по USB как обычная клавиатруа, возможно этого вам будет достаточно?))

Comment: Самое простое - это работа в эмуляции клавиатуры, тогда вообще ничего не нужно дополнительно делать, Далее сканеры с UART интерфейсом и встроенным UART-USB(например на PL2303) либо через BlueTooth. Если сканер имеет собственный уникальный протокол - проще забыть про него.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Физическое устройство сканер ШК подключается по USB как обычная клавиатруа, возможно этого вам будет достаточно?))

Если точно то есть 3 режима:

- USB клавиатура,
- USB эмуляция COM порта,
- OPOS режим

Вас может заинтересовать первый режим - с вашей стороны никаких телодвижений для чтения данных, они будут вводится в любое активное поле для ввода.

Либо же второй режим - с вашей стороны необходимо читать COM port.

Третий режим более сложен и требует изучения документации, но при этом позволяет производить захват оборудования, чтение RAW данных, получение более подробной информации об оборудовании, Типе и данных закодированых в ШК и пр. информацию.

Comment: т.е. получается рисовать обычную форму, делать фокус на поле и запускать сканер? Конечно это как вариант, если штрихкод поврежден и не читается можно его вписать вручную. Такие реализации видел на Windows, но будет ли Android правильно это обрабатывать? Особенно интересует вопрос когда сканер подключен к телефону как ему послать команду сканирования? Ссылку на сам сканер добавил в вопрос.

Comment: @AlekseyMuratov Будет, у меня по долгу службы очень много сканеров ШК, разных фирм, и все которые USB - без всяких заморочек работают со всеми андроид приложениями, и определяются системой как клавиатуры.

Comment: @AlekseyMuratov Команду посылать не нужно. Сканер сам сканирует когда его подносишь к штрихкоду(либо нужно нажать на кнопку на сканере). Многие имеют встроенный детектор движения, то уходят в режим сна если ничего им не делать и просыпаются когда берешь в руку чтобы сканировать.

Comment: большое спасибо за информацию. помогли. думаю вариант с клавиатурой подойдет.